# Passing an int function to a while loop in java

Tags: java, c++11, while-loop

I am implementing the three Missionary and Canniball problem. When implementing it works fine in c++ and python but gives an error in the while loop when implemented in Java. The code in c++ is as follows:

```
/* Variables are as follows:
 * im and ic = initial missionaries and cannibal respectfully
 * fm and fc = final missionaries and cannibal respectfully
 * status = indicates what side we are on
 * select = used in solution() method to determine the boat grouping
 * flag = used to determine boat's current location
 * i = loop counter
 */

int im = 3, ic = 3, i, fm = 0, fc = 0, status = 0, flag = 0, select = 0;

void display(char bpass1, char bpass2)

{

    cout << "\n\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < fm; i++) 
        cout << " M "; 
    for (int i = 0; i < fc; i++)
        cout << " C "; 

    if (flag == 0)
        cout << "     ~~~~~WATER~~~~~<B0(" << bpass1 << "," << bpass2 << ")AT>  ";
    else
        cout << "     <BO(" << bpass1 << "," << bpass2 << ")AT>~~~~~WATER~~~~~  ";
    for (int i = 0; i < im; i++)
        cout << " M ";
    for (int i = 0; i < ic; i++)
        cout << " C ";
}

int win()

{

    return (fc == 3 && fm == 3) ? 0 : 1;
}

/**
 Basic algorithm is as follows:
 * 1 - Get boat's current location
 * 2 - Determine passenger grouping
 * 3 - Make trip
 * 4 - Determine if we won
 * 5 - Repeat until we won
 */


void solution()

{

    while (win()) //In java gives me error here in my IDE. 

    {

        if (!flag)
        {
            switch (select)
            {
                case 1: display('C', ' ');
                        ic++;
                        break;
                case 2: display('C', 'M');
                        ic++; im++;    
                        break;   
            }

            if (((im - 2) >= ic && (fm + 2) >= fc) || (im - 2) == 0)
            {
                im = im - 2;
                select = 1;
                display('M', 'M');
                flag = 1;
            }
            else if ((ic - 2) < im && (fm == 0 || (fc + 2) <= fm) || im == 0)
            {
                ic = ic - 2;
                select = 2;
                display('C', 'C');
                flag = 1;
            }

            else if ((ic--) <= (im--) && (fm++) >= (fc++))
            {
                ic = ic - 1;
                im = im - 1;
                select = 3;
                display('M', 'C');
                flag = 1;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            switch (select)
            {
                case 1: display('M', 'M');
                        fm = fm + 2;
                        break;

                case 2: display('C', 'C');
                        fc = fc + 2;
                        break;   

                case 3: display('M', 'C');
                        fc = fc + 1;
                        fm = fm + 1;
                        break;
            }

            if (win())
            {
                if (((fc > 1 && fm == 0) || im == 0))
                {
                    fc--;
                    select = 1;
                    display('C', ' ');
                    flag = 0;
                }

                else if ((ic + 2) > im)
                {
                    fc--; fm--;
                    select = 2;
                    display('C', 'M');
                    flag = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()

{

    cout << "MISSIONARIES AND CANNIBAL SOLUTION";
    display(' ', ' ');
    solution();
    display(' ', ' ');
    return 0;

}
```

I don't know where am i going wrong.Any replacement of the code with same output(in java) or correction is appreciated.Thanks!!

Output of code should be:

[part 1 of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5bn4.png)
[part 2 of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5LAD.png)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood it correctly, in java `boolean` is a separate type from `Number` type (like int, float, double, char and etc). There is no **implicit** and **explicit** cast between `boolean` and `Number` type so you can't write something like `while (win())` or `if(win())` because return type of `win()` is an int and `while` need a `boolean`! The only way is to return false and true in your `win` function.

```
boolean win() {
    return (fc == 3 && fm == 3) ? false : true;
    /// or better: return !(fc == 3 && fm == 3);
}
```

Comment: `while(win() != 0)` should work as well if that is the issue.

Comment: yes. it is true. but better to use boolean instead of int for conditions. it is more type safe.

Comment: When using bool it doesn't gives me the required output.I know bool is type safe and also works fine in c++ but is not working in java.

Comment: What is the meaning of correct output? I didnt check your code for currect result but it should work if it same as your c++ code  except for while condition

Comment: Edited the question with image links.